# how to add a javascript to an email and send through thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I am trying to add javascript to the email template and my email template is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
    <title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.fontSize = "25px";           
    x.style.color = "red"; 
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<div class="mail">
    <p th:text="#{greeting(${name})}"> Hello, Peter Static</p>
    <div>
          <p th:utext="#{username(${userNamr})}">name</p>
    </div>
     <div>
         <p th:utext="#{password(${password})}">name</p>
     </div>
</div>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

in my controller
 I am using context object to set variable and I am using mimemessage to send the mail my problem  is mail part is working well but javascript part is not working

```
public String registrationHandler(HttpServletRequest request,final Locale locale,Model model) throws Exception {
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
          ctx.setVariable("name", "vignesh");
          ctx.setVariable("userNamr", request.getParameter("name"));
          ctx.setVariable("password", request.getParameter("password"));
          final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage(); 
          final MimeMessageHelper message =  new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8"); // true = multipart
          message.setSubject("User Name And Password");
          message.setFrom("info@example.com");
          message.setTo(request.getParameter("email"));
          final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("mailTemplate.html", ctx);
          message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);
          this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);  
          model.addAttribute("mail", request.getParameter("email"));
          return "registrationSucess";
    }
```

I just want to know how to enable the javascript code in email template via thymeleaf.

Comment: I'm pretty sure emails can't have javascript

Comment: for security reasons i am quite sure no mail program will execute any javascript in mails